# ROS-actions issue in boost::bind

Tags: c++, action, ros

New to ROS here. I am writing a simple server-client ROS code to calculate factorial of a number using actions. The tutorials always show the Fibonacci example, but I want to write a simple code without using any classes (for learning purposes). For that I am following the tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib

The action_server.cpp file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ros/ros.h>
#include<std_msgs/String.h>
#include<actionlib/server/simple_action_server.h>
#include"actions_basics/NumAction.h"

void callbackfunction(actions_basics::NumActionGoalConstPtr& goal, actionlib::SimpleActionServer<actions_basics::NumAction>* action_server){
    ros::Rate r(2);
    bool success = true;

    actions_basics::NumActionFeedback feedback;
    actions_basics::NumActionResult result;

    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Executing operation on server");
    int temp = 1;
    for (auto i = 2; i < goal->goal.num; i++) {
        temp = temp*i;
        feedback.feedback.current_num = temp;
        action_server->publishFeedback(feedback.feedback);
        r.sleep();
    }
    if (success) {
        result.result.factorial_num = feedback.feedback.current_num;
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Succeeded");
        action_server->setSucceeded(result.result);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "action_server");
    ros::NodeHandle nodehandle;
    actionlib::SimpleActionServer<actions_basics::NumAction> action_server(nodehandle, "num_server", boost::bind(&callbackfunction, boost::placeholders::_1, &action_server), false);
    action_server.start();
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

The Num.action file:

```
#goal definition
int32 num
---
#result definition
int32 factorial_num
---
#feedback definition
int32 current_num
```

However I am getting an error `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘boost::shared_ptr<const actions_basics::NumActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&’ from expression of type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const actions_basics::NumGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >’`

I have added the required find_package, include_directories etc for Boost in the CMakeLists.txt.
Help please!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `actions_basics::NumGoalConstPtr& goal` instead of `actions_basics::NumActionGoalConstPtr& goal` as operand in callbackfunction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).